# How to go thru each children in a binary tree?

Tags: php, recursion, binary-tree

I have following database table which can display a binary tree view.

[image: MySQL table]

Interested to find a recursive function in which I can go to each children of the binary tree and get the total number of people group by each rank under a given root node.

For example; if I pass a root id as 2 it should give me the result as follows:

Root > Nisar
Users of Rank 1: 2
Users of Rank 2: 1
Users of Rank 3: 1
Users of Rank 4: 0

Need your support in php code for above.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivetreeiterator.php

Comment: Please post code and tables as text rather than images.

Comment: Can you add more information, like the code with which you connect to the database, which query you launch to get the data in a PHP result set, what that result set looks like in PHP syntax, what the data structure should be of the desired result (unless you are really looking for *text* output)...